# Make a string call a function in JS

Tags: javascript

I want this to work:

I have defined a function:

```
function callback_1() {
 // Do something
}
```

I have a callback string that defines a callback:

```
var functionString = 'callback_' + 1 + '()';
```

I want to make that string actually call the function `callback_1` How do I do that?

Comment: Will eval be sandboxed? I mean can I the defined function be outside eval context?

Comment: have a look at eval, but then try to figure out how you don't need it

Comment: __NOO__ _"eval()"_ is **EVIL**, the only time you _had_ (not have, had) to use it was when parsing JSON back in the days. I've not seen any situation where eval was the only solution since...

Answer (score 6):

As your `functionString` is in fact mainly a function's name, you can do that

```
window['callback_' + 1]();
```

This is much secure than `eval` as it only executes a function you yet have.

If you want to use the `functionString` you have (with its "()" at the end), you can use

```
window[functionString.slice(0, -2)]();
```

Comment: Tried this and it works. Though in the string we need to remove `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: it is working for me

```
        eval(functionString);
```

Comment: Will eval be sandboxed? I mean can the defined function be outside eval context?

Comment: remember that in most cases, `eval` is evil :). dystroy answer is the one to go

Comment: @VladBalmos theres no reason this answer should be downvoted. If you like one answer over another then vote up the one you like.

Comment: @qwertymk: in this case, the answer can produce potentially harmful code, if the eval-string is based on user input or an ajax response. potentially dangerous code is a valid reason for down-voting, says the FAQ

Comment: @qwertymk what makes you think I down voted? Regardless, I am entitled to up / down vote based on the quality of the answer. See Elias comment on why it may be down voted